# Multiple warnings when building wso2 esb

Tags: maven, wso2, esb

I have to build WSO2 Enterprise Service Bus using source files. I use Apache Maven 3.2.2 as described in the documentation here: 
https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB481/Building+from+Source

After running **mvn clean install > D:\log.txt** there are multiple warnings at the beginning that sound rather threatening.

```
[WARNING] It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten the stability of your build.
[WARNING] For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support building such malformed projects.
```

To get rid of them I have to edit POM files manually.

**Is there a correct way of building WSO2 ESB?**

Comment: I see that I should change the version of Maven from 3.2.2 to 3.0.x.

Comment: Maven version 3.0.x is recommended to build WSO2 products : https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB481/Installation+Prerequisites

Comment: After changing to Maven version 3.0.5 the warnings are still here. They are due to https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/Maven+3.x+Compatibility+Notes#Maven3.xCompatibilityNotes-AutomaticPluginVersionResolution